# Does x ≽ y imply x > y or x ~ y in preferences?

Tags: preferences, theory, proof

Mas Collel Micro Theory question:

Suppose that X is a set. Let ≽ be a binary preference on X. And ~ represents indifference defined from ≽.

If ≽ satisfy completeness, is it okay to assume that:

x ≽ y implies either x >y or x ~ y ?

My homemade proof:

≽ is complete -> x ≽ y or y ≽ x

This implies either:

1. x ≽ y & not(y ≽ x) => x > y
2. x ≽ y & y ≽ x => x ~ y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual definition of $x \succeq y$ is that either $x \sim y$ or $x \succ y$ hold. Your proof and the assumption of completeness are not necessary.

---

One could also start from $\succeq$ and $\sim$ and define $x \succ y$ in such a way that $x \succeq y$ holds but $x \sim y$ does not. Even in this case, it is true without any additional assumptions that $x \succeq y$ implies either $x \sim y$ or $x \succ y$.

Comment: Late comment: The usual definition of $x \succeq y$ is not that either $x \sim y$ or $x \succ y$ hold. The relation $\succeq$ is what is given, and then $x \sim y$ and $x \succ y$ are defined via ($x \succeq y$ and $y \succeq x$) and ($x \succeq y$ and not($y \succeq x$)), respectively. So a proof, though easy, is necessary.

Comment: @VARulle I guess "usual" depends on what you read, but you are probably right. Also, did you happen to see the part of my answer under the line horizontal line?

Comment: I happened to see that lower part, but I chose to comment on the upper part, since the "usual definition" of $x \succeq y$ is quite standard. "Starting from $\succeq$ and $\sim$", as the lower part suggests, is only possible after already having defined $\sim$, of course.